# JavaFX: how do I use concurrency to read the output of an external process and display it in an FXML TextArea?

Tags: java, concurrency, javafx-2, javafx, external-process

Here is a simple example of my problem.  Let's say I have a java app that displays a GUI using JavaFX.  When the user hits the start button, the app pings an external server for 15 seconds.  The idea is that the during this 15 seconds, the output of the ping process should appear in the GUI of the app.  This is what I have so far:

1) mypackage/App.fxml file that I use to build the JavaFX layout.
2) mypackage/AppController.java file
3) mypackage/App.java file

In the fxml file I specify a controller in the AppController.java file for when the start button is pushed.  This controller looks like this:

```
@FXML
private void handleStartAction(ActionEvent event) {
    try {
        String ping_command = "ping -c 15 google.com";
        console.println("\nCOMMAND> "+ping_command);
        Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(ping_command); 
        p.waitFor(); 
        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()) );
        String line=null;
        while((line=reader.readLine())!=null)
        {
            console.println(line);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) { 
        console.println(e);
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is that the app just hangs for the full 15 seconds while waiting for the external process to complete, instead of reading the output from the process as it appears, once per second.

Comment: Could you please post the code where you are updating the contents of the text area with the output of the command?